# Parse.com JS SDK not loading in PhoneGap/Cordova

Tags: cordova, parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to load Parse.com's JS SDK in a Phonegap/Cordova application.

Here's what my www/index.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>

        <!-- Sets initial viewport load and disables zooming  -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">

        <!-- Makes your prototype chrome-less once bookmarked to your phone's home screen -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

        <!-- Include the compiled Ratchet CSS -->
        <link href="css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="cordova.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Parse.initialize("MY_APPLICATION_ID", "MY_JS_KEY");
        </script>
        <script src="js/ratchet.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="init()">

    </body>
</html>
```

I have replaced `MY_APPLICATION_ID` and `MY_JS_KEY` with appropriate strings from Parse.com.

The app loads fine in browser (Safari on Mac) and I'm able to make API calls to Parse Cloud successfully.

However, if I package the app using Cordova and run it on a mobile device (iOS/Android) it fails to load Parse JS SDK from parsecdn.com, therefore this error message (for example in Android):

```
10-17 06:03:42.382: I/chromium(11792): [INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Parse is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (20)
```

I've tried running in Android Emulator and a real iPhone device (connected via USB to Xcode), both of which fails to make API calls to Parse.com, and also verified that these devices have an active Internet connection.

It's strange everything works perfectly and it even uploads and stores objects successfully to Parse.com, when browsing locally using Safari on Mac.

What could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by saving Parse.js locally and loading from there instead of loading from the CDN.

It seems like the real issue here is PhoneGap not being able to properly load remote JS.

Some have suggested loading all remote scripts before `cordova.js`, which also didn't work in my case.

Comment: actually [you \*MUST*](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#deviceready) wait for the `deviceready` event before you can do ANYTHING.  Also as for *best practice* load as many assets as you can locally. This might help too - [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)